# How to Show Download and show a Bitamp image from URI in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, bitmap

i just wrote this code:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    String latEiffelTower = "48.858235";
    String lngEiffelTower = "2.294571";
    String url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + latEiffelTower +   "," + lngEiffelTower + "&zoom=15&size=200x200&sensor=false";
    try {
        ImageView i = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(url).getContent());
        i.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

then i want to download a static image bitmap from google static map and the sen that on imageview, but my program stops when i run it, how can show this bitmap image in this code?did i use to any special permission or anything else?

and this is my main.xml

```
 RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 tools:context=".MyActivity">

 <TextView
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/image"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Universal Image Loader module. It can be found at https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

```
public class WebImageLoader {
    DisplayImageOptions options;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;

    public WebImageLoader(Context context) {

        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showImageOnLoading( context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_stub) )
                .showImageForEmptyUri(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_empty))
                .showImageOnFail(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_error))
                .cacheInMemory(false)
                .cacheOnDisk(true)
                .considerExifParams(true)
                .build();

        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        if (!imageLoader.isInited()) {
            imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));
        }
    }

    public void displayImage(ImageView imageView,String imageURL) {
        try {
            imageLoader.displayImage(imageURL, imageView, options);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            //Handle the exception
        }
    }
 }
```

To use it

```
WebImageLoader imageLoader = new WebImageLoader(context);
ImageView imgProductImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgProductImage);
imageLoader.displayImage(imgProductImage,url);
```

Thanks,
Noorul

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [volley](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html), your program stops because you cannot run network code on android main thread since its reserved for UI task

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use **Picasso** to download images i.e:

```
String latEiffelTower = "48.858235";
String lngEiffelTower = "2.294571";
String url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + latEiffelTower +   "," + lngEiffelTower + "&zoom=15&size=200x200&sensor=false";
ImageView i = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);

Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(url).into(i);
```

For more information visit [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso)